# Query Performance - four Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

my Graph question is:
"Which Player played most frequently against each other"

I queried following Cypher:

```
match (p:Player)-[:PLAYS_IN]->(t:Team)-[:PLAYED]->(g:Game)<-[:PLAYED]-(tt:Team)<-[:PLAYS_IN]-(pp:Player) 
USING SCAN p:Player USING SCAN pp:Player  
return p.Lastname, pp.Lastname, count(pp) order by count(pp) desc limit 100;
```

Number of 
Player: 158310
Game: 215068
Team: 218960

Heap is 6G, CPU are 4 cores.

This Query does take hours and does not finish.
How should i optimize it?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: See the answer on the google group ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can simplify the problem by first finding which teams played mosted each other and based on that find the players. I'm not sure if that assumption oversimplfies the problem.

```
match (t:Team)-[:PLAYED]->(g:Game)<-[:PLAYED]-(tt:Team)
with t, tt order by count(g) desc limit 1
match  (p:Player)-[:PLAYS_IN]->(t:Team)-[:PLAYED]->(g:Game)<-[:PLAYED]-(tt:Team)<-[:PLAYS_IN]-(pp:Player) 
return p.Lastname, pp.Lastname, count(pp) order by count(pp) desc limit 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But i think probably i went into to cartesian product issue:
    neo4j-sh (?)$ match (g:Game) return count(g);                                                           
    +----------+
    | count(g) |
    +----------+
    | 215067   |
    +----------+
    1 row
    450 ms
    neo4j-sh (?)$ match (t:Team)-[:PLAYED]->(g:Game)<-[:PLAYED]-(tt:Team) using scan g:Game return count(g);
    +----------+
    | count(g) |
    +----------+
    | 4628408  |
    +----------+
    1 row
    35260 ms
    neo4j-sh (?)$